# C# производительность приложения

Tags: c#, http

Есть консольное приложение, которое подключается к веб сервису, и запрашивает данные. Есть вопросы по производительности этого приложения. С момента запуска до получения информации проходит около минуты. По логам веб-сервиса, API отрабатывает от 4 до 6 секунд, и происходит вывод информации в консоль. Пример: от комментария в коде "запуск приложения" до "получаем ответ в консоль" проходит около 50 секунд, далее по логам веб-сервиса вижу, что происходит вызов api,и через 6 секунд получаю ответ. WireShark показывает что от веб-сервиса приходит HTTP 100 только на 50й секунде. Вопрос: как можно отследить, что происходит в эти 50 секунд?

```
        //запуск приложения
        WSPORTTYPEClient client = new WSPORTTYPEClient();
        OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)client.InnerChannel);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                                new MySoapSecurityHeader("login", "password"));

        client.Open();

        DSContractCreditGetPaySchedulePlanReq req = new DSContractCreditGetPaySchedulePlanReq();
        /* тут находятся данные для запроса */

        DSContractCreditGetPaySchedulePlanRes res = client.dsContractCreditGetPaySchedulePlan(req);
        //получаем ответ в консоль.
        foreach(var i in res.ContractCreditPaySchedulePlanList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
                i.Number
                ,i.Amount
                ,i.DateStart
                ,i.DateEnd
                ,i.PayDateStart
                ,i.PayDateEnd
                ,i.TotalAmount);
        }
        client.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `По логам веб-сервиса, API отрабатывает от 4 до 6 секунд`... `WireShark показывает что от веб-сервиса приходит HTTP 100 только на 50й секунде` задержка видимо либо на стороне сервиса, либо на стороне транспорта между сервисом и консолью.

Comment: @tym32167 Интересная вещь, если после получения ответа от веб-сервиса, я не закрою соединение, а сделаю еще один запрос с другими входными данными, ответ получаю за 2-4 секунды. Tcpdump показывает, что от моего приложения приходит соединение после старта приложения, только после 30 секунд. Т.е. получается 30 секунд устанавливается соединение?

Comment: Может быть да. А может быть и нет. А может быть сервис засыпает, если нет подключений, и просыпание сервиса занимает 30 секунд. Тут не скажешь наверняка.